# MIPS reversing string with Add a space

Tags: assembly, mips

How to Add a space between every two characters of the input word and then print it out.

In my program it can reversing a String

```
Loop:

        sub     $t2, $t2, 1     #this statement is now before the 'load address'
        la      $t0, buffer($t2)   #loading value
        lb      $a0, ($t0)
        syscall


        bnez    $t2, Loop       

        li      $v0, 10              #program done: terminating
        syscall
        jr $ra
```

My Result

Enter string: `Hello`

Original: `Hello`

Reversed: `olleH`

but How to Add a space between every two characters of the input word

Enter string: `Hello`

Original: `H e l l o`

Reversed: `o l l e H`

Comment: The code you provided does not reverse a string

Comment: sorry i forgot to add reverse code

Comment: You should format the code correctly. To do that you have to select the code and click on `{ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is printing a reversed string stored in buffer, but the reversed string is not stored back.
If that was your intent, then all you need is to print a space after each character printed.

That is accomplished by adding these two lines after the syscall that prints each character (before the `bnez    $t2, Loop` )

```
  li $a0, ' '
  syscall
```